# where can i use the for?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

> i make a instabot and i want every time it use from one username and password and login and close browser and start again and login an other username and password and use another account and repeat that for many times but i dont know where use (for)or (while) in my code>
>    `**usenm.send_keys(self.username)**`

````
     #import from selenium 
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time     
    import random


    #my class
    class INntagramBot:

        def __init__(self,username,password):
            self.username=username
            self.password=password
            self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()
    #THIS FUNCTION IS FOR CLOSE browser
        def webbrosercloser(self):
            self.driver.close()
            #THIS FUNCTION IS FOR LOGIN
        def login(self):
            driver=self.driver
            driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
            usenm=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
            usenm.clear()
          `#HERE I USE THE USERNAME I THINK HERE I USE FOR  `  
            **usenm.send_keys(self.username)**
            passw=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
            passw.clear()
            passw.send_keys(self.password)
            passw.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            time.sleep(4)
            driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/B8zjvEAhux8/")
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.find_element_by_class_name('_8-yf5 ').click()
            #username and password    
    username=['bazamcartoon','taghaviali34']
    password="0909"
    bb=INntagramBot(username,password)
    bb.login()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
    #import from selenium 
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time     
    import random


    #my class
    class INntagramBot:

        def __init__(self,username,password):
            self.username=username
            self.password=password
            self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()
    #THIS FUNCTION IS FOR CLOSE browser
        def webbrosercloser(self):
            self.driver.close()
            #THIS FUNCTION IS FOR LOGIN
        def login(self):
            driver=self.driver
            driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
            usenm=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
            usenm.clear()
          `#HERE I USE THE USERNAME I THINK HERE I USE FOR  `  
            **usenm.send_keys(self.username)**
            passw=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
            passw.clear()
            passw.send_keys(self.password)
            passw.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            time.sleep(4)
            driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/B8zjvEAhux8/")
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.find_element_by_class_name('_8-yf5 ').click()

    #username and password    

    username=['bazamcartoon','taghaviali34']
    password="0909"

    for i in range(0, n):-----------> n is the number of times you want to call the function.
        bb=INntagramBot(username,password)
        bb.login()`
```

If you want to run it with a while loop , you can do this :

```
i = 0

while i < n:                ------------------->  n is same as above, the number of times you want to iterate

    bb=INntagramBot(username,password)
    bb.login()
    i+=1
```

Comment: i have many accounts and i want every times it logs on  one of them (for example  i have a post and i need many likes in instagram post and  i want these account likes my post  my problem is in this code ```usenm.send_keys(self.username)``` when i send the keys this keys are my accounts

Comment: i dont know how use from (for loop ) in this code ```usenm.send_keys(self.username)``` and username (i have many username but my instabot just using from the first username)

Comment: you also have a password array ?

Comment: yes i have password array but used one password for all users